# Context free grammar for AN

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I need to write Context free grammar for describing moves in a game of chess using the Algebric Notation.  Can anyone help me get started.  f.ex. how do I write this for this move:
 Bb5 Bd7.

Comment: What do you mean by "the algebraic notation"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)

Answer (score 0):

For your example, $Bb7$ means that the bishop is on square $b7$. From this square, the bishop has nine different possible squares to move to. We could write this in our CFG as
$$Bb7 \rightarrow Bc8 \; | \; Ba6 \; | \; Ba8 \; | \; Bc6 \; | \; Bd5 \; | \; Be4 \; | \; Bf3 \; | \; Bg2 \; | \; Bh1$$
Then we would have to do the same for $Bc8, Ba6$, etc. to give all possible moves for the bishop.

Answer (score 0):

An answer and discussion is contained in this SO article and answer I provided there:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330606/bnf-input-going-to-wrong-nonterminal